# Mark inbox item as read when reaching its relevant post from email

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, email

Suppose someone has answered my question, I got notification in my email and clicked the email link to get to the answer.

When doing this, I see there's still a notification in the top bar.

Can the relevant inbox item be marked as "read", thus making the red number go away?

Comment: what happens if you refresh the browser?

Comment: So are you suggesting that when you click on the link in your email, the notification should disappear?

Comment: That's NOT a bug. Valid feature request, going to change into one now so if you won't agree feel free to rollback.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA - well.. when you click on a notification in the app the bubble disappears in the browser...

Comment: I think notification means for me that after I read the message, it should disappear automatically. And even now, when you guys are adding new comments, the bubble still does not go away.

Comment: @mehow nothing will happen, as long as we don't manually click the red number, it will stay there.

Comment: They are two seperate systems however. I can understand that this is probably desirable behaviour, but it would require new stuff to make it work, rather than fixing old stuff that was always supposed to do this

Comment: Say, I am reading all your `6` comments now, but as long as I don't click the number bubble on the top bar, refreshing doesn't help. The notification is still there. So my question is not restricted to the new answers, but also to the new comments.

Comment: in case you didnt click it from your email and just logged in then you wouldnt have a notification so you wouldnt know right away if someones answered or replied to you.

Comment: @mehow I think currently the `highlight` feature is doing a great job in reminding me there is a new answer and which one is the new answer.